# r function stack: different in command and rstudio

Tags: r

Very strange
both under R version 4.0.2, the function `stack` performance different in command line and rstudio.
Example:

```
tmp= matrix(1:4,ncol=2)
stack(tmp)
```

the output in rstudio:

```
DataFrame with 4 rows and 3 columns
        row   col     value
  <integer> <Rle> <integer>
1         1     1         1
2         2     1         2
3         1     2         3
4         2     2         4
```

however, in the terminal:

```
Error in rep.int(factor(names(x), unique(names(x))), lengths(x)) :
```

invalid 'times' value

**Very curious WHY**
Anyone else ever found this?

Comment: Are you running the same version of R with the same packages loaded? It would be helpful to show the output of `sessionInfo()` for both your command line and RStudio consoles.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I have checked.

Comment: There are multiple packages that have `stack` function.  The error you received is from `utils::stack` which is a base R.  Maybe in your `Rstudio` session, other `stack` from a package is loaded.  Can you check `conflicts()`

Comment: Well, you should still add the output from `sessionInfo()` from both to your question so that we can also compare and verify that everything is the same. It really seems like something must be different.

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry my fault. There are some additional packages in the rstudio.

Comment: @MrFlick I will add the output now.

Comment: I would suggest to test on Rstudio on a fresh session with no packages loaded and check if you are still getting the same issue

Comment: @akrun Thank you.  I tried conflicts() and find two "stacks". May I ask how can I locate which package the "stack" function from?

Comment: @SunnySong you can just do `?stack` and it will show those multiple links

Comment: @akrun I have done this before, only utils and rlang. But even I library both in the terminal, I ended in the same result.

Comment: Can you try on a fresh Rstudio session with no library loaded.  Your output from `stack` shows a tibble and that is kind of confusing because the input `tmp` is a matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234931/discussion-between-sunny-song-and-akrun).

Comment: @akrun I found it. `library(S4Vectors)`

Answer (score 0):

Found the key:
I loaded a packages called "S4Vectors" before, so use this in the terminal:

```
S4Vectors::stack
```